# Django sorting without duplicates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Model structure in screenshot. I want structure in template as in the sreen.

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8bl3.png)

in view i get object:

```
class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Article
        template_name = 'info_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['article'] = self.get_object()
    return context
```

Model

```
class Article(models.Model):
        news = models.ManyToManyField(News)

class News(models.Model):
          type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
          title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Type(models.Model):
          name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Template:

```
{% for news in article.news.all %}
   <p>{{ news.type.name }}</p>
    <p>{{ news.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

If in template i use cycle for->i have structure like this: type1: news 1; type1: news 2;type 2: news 3.

Comment: What are the types? Is it a ForeignKey to a Type model? Show the model definitions.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman add model

Comment: where's your problem? what's the code you're using now in your template to cycle through the various objects? Your `get_context_data` method doesn't return anything.

Comment: @dirkgroten i add information. i hope, it is more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a default ordering to your `News` class:

```
class News(models.Model):

    (...)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['type', 'title']
```

Then in your template's forloop:

```
{% for news in article.news.all %}
    {% ifchanged news.type %}
        {% if forloop.counter != 1 %}</ul>{% endif %}
        <h2>{{ news.type.name }}</h2>
        <ul>
    {% endifchanged %}
    <li>
        {{ news.title }}
    </li>
 {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

Since the `News` objects are ordered by `type`, it will add the heading every time a new `type` is encountered.